# iOS - Terminated due to memory issue error

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsurlsession, digest

So i am doing a network calls to retrieve image and using that i am show a kind of a video.
After a while i can see the memory lose and energy impact:
[image]

after a while my app crushed and i got :"Terminated due to memory issue error"

Before that i got that error from the image caller method:"error from dataResponse:The operation couldn’t be completed. No space left on device"

This are the two method i use:

```
class InstallationViewController: BaseViewController {

    func imageCaller(url: String , success: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let handler = AuthenticateHandler()
    self.urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: handler, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    self.imageThumbnailTask = urlSession?.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!) { data, res, err in

        if err != nil {
            print("error from dataResponse:\(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")")
            failure()
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let imageData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                success(image)
                URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

            }
        }
    }
    self.imageThumbnailTask?.resume()
}

 func imageThumbnailcall() {
    self.indicaotrTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.HandleOverTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    self.imageCaller( url: self.isShowingThermal ? self.thermalUrl : self.visualUrl, success: { (image) in

        self.indicaotrTimer?.invalidate()

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.backGroundImageView.image = image
        }
        if self.isInVC {
            self.imageThumbnailcall()
        }
    }) {
        self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Worth mentioning that this line:

```
   let handler = AuthenticateHandler()
    self.urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: handler, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

for digest protocol

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a retain cycle in your closure in the `imageThumbnailcall` function.
The closure creates a strong reference to `self`, and since it's a recursive function you will run out of memory pretty quick.
You need to capture self as `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` in the closure.
Example using `[unowned self]`:

```
func imageThumbnailcall() {
    self.indicaotrTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.HandleOverTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    self.imageCaller( url: self.isShowingThermal ? self.thermalUrl : self.visualUrl, success: { [unowned self] (image) in

    self.indicaotrTimer?.invalidate()

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.backGroundImageView.image = image
    }
    if self.isInVC {
        self.imageThumbnailcall()
    }
    }) {
        self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

If you want to learn more about

Comment: I think i have tried it in the past , but i will make sure right now.
the reference of self is regarding backGroundImageView?

Comment: So everything that refers to self in that closure will lead to a reference cycle. This is because self already has a strong reference to the closure (self.imageCaller), and when you use self in a closure without a capture list, the closure creates a strong reference back to self. And that creates a reference cycle.

Comment: So you were right.
It improves dramatically the memory usage.
I have one problem:
when i am doing weak self i need to modify all the self in the closer to "self?"
then i need to modify self?.isInVC to (self?.isInVC)!
thats crushing my app later.

any idea?

Comment: and still i am getting "error from dataResponse:The operation couldn’t be completed. No space left on device" some times

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're recursively calling `imageThumbnailcall`.  If you don't end the recursion at some point, you could see exactly the symptoms that you are reporting.

```
   if self.isInVC {
        self.imageThumbnailcall()
   }
```

Are you making sure to set `isInVC` properly so you break out of the recursive loop?

Comment: Yes,
the whole point is to call it recursively to have a kind of video

Comment: k. Thought I'd ask.  As long as you've got something that is setting `isInVC` false before you run out of memory and overflow.  You might try using Instruments and watching your allocations to help debug.

Comment: Another related thought would be the call to `isInVC`.   Doesn't look like that's on the main thread?   If you're doing anything w/UI that might be a problem.  You might try moving that to the main thread.

Comment: I do so...:

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.backGroundImageView.image = image
        }